# Cropping images in angular

Tags: angular

I am searching for a plugin for Angular to crop images before uploading it to the database, I have searched all the day, but all the plugins I have found was even deprecated or not satisfying my needs.

What I specifically want is a plugin that:

1. Zoom in and out the photo.
2. Crop the photo.
3. Change the format of the photo.

the best choice I have found was:

1. [angular-image-cropper](https://bcabanes.github.io/angular-image-cropper/)
2. [Andy Shora image cropper](https://www.andyshora.com/angular-image-cropper.html)
3. [ngx-image-cropper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-cropper)

[The first one](https://bcabanes.github.io/angular-image-cropper/) the almost what I want, but unfortunately it's deprecated and I can't use it or don't know how to use it.

I want something similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wB3BJ.gif).

Is there a method to use the first one in angular 13? or is there a good alternative for it?

Answer (score 1):

Would [ngx-image-cropper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-cropper) work for you? Glancing over the docs it should be able to do what you want, just some minor touches to UI side. Snapping to grid, highlight lines etc.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-image-cropper?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: It's not really what I am looking for because it doesn't have a realiable zooming option, and also image can't be dragged throughout the boundaries of it's parent like Angular-Image-Cropper

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but the image cropper in this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/image-cropper?file=app%2Fimage-cropper%2Futils%2Fexif.utils.ts) has a zoom option that might be what you're looking for